# How to compare datagrid column value to today date and display value in status column (last column) in c#

Tags: c#

I have a income form where it shows status of the member which is like expired or active

below is the datagridview image

[image]

this is the code block I have tried to get expire date to match with the today date and show status
this is not working

```
private void dataGridView2_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; y++)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime expdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[9].ErrorText);

        if (expdate > today.AddDays(3))
        {
            dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my sql table TABLE NAME IS tblIncome

[image]

WHAT I WANT IS

1. want to show status as expired if today date matches with expire date
2. if not show status as active
3. I want to show status as (3 days to expire) if date reaches 27 days

I am new to c# development so please excuse my method of asking question help me out. thanks to all great people who is taking their valuable time to answer my problem

Comment: The line of code… `DateTime expdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[9].ErrorText);` … looks quite odd. Why is the code trying to parse the cells “error text” as a `DateTime` object … ? … In addition, if the data in the DB is of a `Date` type, then you should not have to “parse” the value. You should be able to directly cast the cells value to a `DateTime` object. However, this depends on how the data is filled in the grid.

Comment: Also, it appears the code is getting the “error text” from the cell in column 9 which is odd since there does not appear to be a `Cells[9]` in the picture of the grid. Can you clarify any of this? Lastly … Even though the logic looks backwards in the `if` statement… executing the code … `dataGridView2.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;` … is going to set ALL the cells in the grid red … ? … is this intended?

Comment: @JohnG i got this code block from the internet...cell 9 is the cell next to status....status is cell 8...i used cell 9 to check..... can you please give me a code to import the date from sql in place of my code DateTime expdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[9].ErrorText);

Comment: Well… I hate to disagree with you, however, when you reference the cells in the grid by an `int` index like… `Cells[9]` … then this would actually be column 10. This is because the indexing of the columns starts at zero (0) not One (1). In the picture… `MemID` would be column zero (0) and would be referenced like… `Cells[0]` and the last column would be `Cells[8]`. So technically there is no `Cells[9]` in the picture of the grid. This is one reason it is better to reference the cells by the column name… something like… `Cells[“edate”]`.

Comment: Further, if you want to get the cells `DateTime` value and the underlying `DataSource` to the grid has defined that column as a `Date` column… then you can do something like… `DateTime expdate = (DateTime)dataGridView2.Rows[y].Cells[“edate”].Value;` … You obviously could still use the `int` index value as opposed to the name of the column and you should get the same result.

Comment: @JohnG  thank you for your valuable lesson..i actually found and implemented another method to solve my problem.approached with a different method to show the status. also i have a hidden column there in the grid called id...you can see that in the database before the memid..i forgot to mention that before..i wasnt clear on my question